# citation call-outs: not always "et al", sometimes full author list

Tags: citing, natbib

I am having an odd problem; sometimes the full list of authors is inserted in the text, ie. the citation is not shortened to `name et al.` (which is what I want). I am confident it is not an error in the bibtex entry, as it happens for the same citation, when the cite key is simply copied and pasted from the bib file. The only potential pattern I can spot as to when full author list is cited, is sometimes it does it for the first citation in a new `\section` environment. 
I am using the `natbib` package with the `report` document class.
Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Please indicate how the `natbib` package is loaded in your document. Is it possibly loaded with the option `longnamesfirst`? Which bibliography style do you use? Please also give some examples of the actual citation commands that give rise to the citations listing all author names.

Comment: Thank you, It was the longnamesfirst option causing the problem.

Comment: @Mico Wanna answer that?

Comment: @Johannes_B - Done. :-)

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're loading the `natbib` package with the option `longnamesfirst`. This option, if set, tells natbib to generate citation call-outs that include the surnames of *all authors* the first time a given entry with three or more authors is cited; all subsequent citation call-outs of the same entry using the `\citet` and `\citep` macros will be of the form `first-surname et al`.

If you don't want this behavior, don't specify the option `longnamesfirst`.

Comment: Nice :_) :-) ..

Comment: I have the same mistake, however, I do not call `longnamesfirst` and still have the same issue. These are the packages that I load: \documentclass[12pt]{article} \usepackage{pdflscape} \usepackage[]{graphicx} \usepackage{alltt} \usepackage{tikz-cd} \usepackage{amssymb} \usepackage{blindtext} \usepackage{tikz} \usepackage{amsmath} \usepackage{caption} \usepackage{float} \usepackage{rotating} \usepackage{booktabs} \usepackage{pdfpages} \usepackage{ragged2e} \usepackage{xcolor} \usepackage{setspace} \usepackage{fancyhdr} \usepackage{threeparttable} \usepackage[natbibapa,maxcitenames=2]{apacite} \

Comment: @Alex_P - It appears you're using the [apacite](https://ctan.org/pkg/apacite) citation management package, which (a) implements the APA6-vintage formatting guidelines and (b) has very little in common with the `natbib` citation management package. (All the package's `natbibapa` option does is to enable `\citet` and `\citep` syntax.) Please study the user guide of the `apacite` package for more information about the APA6 rules for truncating long lists of authors upon either first citation or repeat citation callouts.

Comment: @Alex_P - Incidentally, the option `maxcitenames=2` is not valid syntax as far as the `apacite` package is concerned. (Did you maybe copy this option from `biblatex` syntax? Not a good idea...) You should be getting an error message about an invalid or unrecognized option; don't ignore error messages.